# check older verisons in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer

we have internet explorer version 11.

We are trying to check our site in older verisons of Internet explorer.

so when i tried with F12  > Emulation > NOthing is displaying.

[image]

please help me how i can check older verisons in IE 11

Comment: Potentially, it's because it's miscoded and IE breaks but, without a link or example markup that shows the problem, anything said is just a wild guess and even off topic for here.

Comment: Questions about the [usage of web browsers and other software](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) not directly related to operating a website is considered off-topic here. You might be able to ask this over at [Super User](http://superuser.com/), but be sure to search for related questions there first.